# In Evernote, is it possible to have multiple separate pages in a single note?

Tags: evernote

In Evernote, is it possible to have multiple separate pages in a single note?

Answer (score 2):

Your question represents a longstanding gripe among Evernote users, myself included. While they allow merging of notes, splitting them is not supported, and neither is the creation of separate pages within a single note. (The closest you could get might be uploading a multi-page pdf into a single note.)

Apart from Note Taker for OS X, I can't think of any that provide multi-page functionality.